# I can't install Duplicated flutter app on one device

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am working on a project and I had to break the app into two. Both connect to the same android project on firebase. I copied the original file from my downloads folder to desktop and worked on both separately. when I install the one in my downloads folder and try installing the one in the desktop folder, it will uninstall the one from downloads one before in installing the new one. I guess that is because they both have the same package name. I don't thing I can change the package name since that is what the I used to create the android app on firebase.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same Firebase project for more than one app.

So you should update the package name for one and add the app with the updated package name to Firebase.